# Find a character in multiple places python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, character

How would one go about finding the positions of a certain character that appears multiple times in python.

E.G:

If I input the string "Lots of foxes" how would I find each of the positions of "O" and display them independently

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accomplish that with a simple `for` loop like so:

```
def find_position(astring, acharacter):
    positions = []
    for c in range(len(astring)):
        if astring[c] == acharacter:
            positions.append(c)
    return positions
```

And test it:

```
a = find_position("Lots of foxes", 'o')
print a
```

prints `[1, 5, 9]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> import re
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer('o',  'Lots of foxes')]
[1, 5, 9]
```

Or, if you want case insensitive search:

```
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer('O',  'Lots of foxes', re.IGNORECASE)]
[1, 5, 9]
```

---

Or, without using the regular expression:

```
>>> [i for i, k in enumerate('Lots of foxes') if k == 'o']
[1, 5, 9]
```

Comment: which requres "import re" in case it's not clear which might not be ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regexp:

```
for idx, val in enumerate("Lots of foxes"):
     if val == "O":
         print(idx)
```

If you want the match to be case insesitive, just change the line `val == "O"` with `val.upper() == "0"`.